# How to send Javascript list to angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I am trying to achieve is send a list of zip codes from my JavaScript function that gets a range based on the distance and zip code that the user enters. Once I get my list of zip codes, send the list to my angular controller.

Originally, the scope below would grab the zip code that was entered by the user from the form (see below):

```
$scope.GetCurrentZip = function (){
        try{
            $http.get("../remote/ReturnZipCodes.cfm")
                    .then(function(response){
                        $scope.searchParam.Zip = response.data;
                    })
            }
            else{ console.log('No geolocation'); }
        }
        catch(err) { console.log(err.message); }
    }
```

I would like to use the same scope that I have above. However, instead of grabbing the value that was entered by the user, I would like to grab the list that I obtain from the function instead.

The following is the JavaScript function that generates the list of zip codes:

```
   var rad = function(x) {
    return x * Math.PI / 180;
  };

  var getDistance = function(p1, p2) {
    var R = 6378137; // Earth’s mean radius in meter
    var dLat = rad(p2.lat - p1.lat);
    var dLong = rad(p2.lon - p1.lon);
    var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
      Math.cos(rad(p1.lat)) * Math.cos(rad(p2.lat)) * Math.sin(dLong / 2) * Math.sin(dLong / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c;
    return d; // returns the distance in meter
  };

  function getZipCodes() {
        var miles = document.getElementById("miles").options[document.getElementById("miles").selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
        if (typeof zip === 'undefined' || typeof miles === 'undefined' || !zip.length || !miles.length) return false;

    var zips = getZips();
        var zip_list = "";
    if (zips.length) {
      // var list_item = "";
      // for (i=0;i<zips.length;i++) {
      //   console.log(zips[i]);
      // }
            zip_list = zips.join();
    }
        return zip_list;
  }

  function getZips() {
    var zipcode1 = getZipInfo(zip);
    var res = [];

    if (typeof zipcode1 === "undefined") return false;
    for (i=0; i<zipinfo.length; i++) {
      var zipcode2 = zipinfo[i];
      var distance = getDistance(zipcode1, zipcode2);

      //Convert meters into miles
      distance = distance/1609.344;
      if (distance <= miles) {
        res.push(zipcode2.zip);
      }
    }
    return res;
  }

  function getZipInfo(zip) {
    for (i=0; i<zipinfo.length; i++) {
      if (zipinfo[i].zip == zip) return zipinfo[i];
    }
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** As stated by @charlietfl, I was not clear with what I was asking in my question and I do apologize for any confusion.

What I was asking is I would like to retrieve the list of zip codes that was generated in my JavaScript function GetZips().

As suggested by @charlietfl (thanks for your help once more), all I needed to do is the following:

```
    $scope.GetCurrentZip = function (){
        try{
                $scope.Zip = getZips();
            }
        catch(err) {}
    }
```

**Update:** @LSD pointed out that it will not pass do to the values passing in are not in a array. Is it possible to change the scope to accept the list? The list is a string.

Comment: Read this several times and not at all clear what you are asking to do or what the specific problem is

Comment: @charlietfl: I would like to pass the list of zip codes I got from my JavaScript Function to the scope GetCurrentZip

Comment: And what specific problem are you having doing that? Where are those functions now? Putting them in an angular service would be the right thing to do with them

Comment: Also are you saying you want to replace the `$http`? Whole question needs clarifications

Comment: @charlietfl: What you mean by specific problem doing that? What is that? The functions are in the same file as the form. And no, not saying I would like to replace the $http. What I am saying I would like to replace "$scope.searchParam.Zip = response.data;" with the list I got from the JavaScript function

Comment: Then what is the `$http` supposed to be for? As for replacing it just do `$scope.searchParam.Zip = getZips()` or whichever function returns what you want. Also not appropriate in an angular app to be doing dom searches like `document.getElementById("miles")`. Use `ng-model` to bind form controls to scope

Comment: @charlietfl: Thanks for you help. I thought it would be a different approach than that. And as far as I am aware of the $http makes a request to the server, and returns a response.

Comment: Yes that's what $http does. But within your $http you assign response to same scope property you say you now want to assign from other functions. Very confusing. Strongly suggest you update the question with a lot more clarity

Comment: @charlietfl: Ahh I see. You are right and I removed it.

Comment: @charlietfl: Thank you for your patience

Comment: The Zipcodes do not push into array . concat with a delimater and stored in a hidden field.Then the hiden field value can take to angular envirnment by the Id of the hiden field

Comment: @LDS: Can you show me. I have been trying and the list isnt going through

Comment: @LDS: After looking over the javascript, it is stored in a list. I have posted the code above. Does it need to be stored in a array?

Comment: @LDS: So I stored my list of zip codes in a hidden input <input type="hidden" id="zipsWithinRadius" value="" />. How can I use these values in my controller?

Comment: your zipcodes should be separated by adelemeter like ; or ! or sothingelse.

Comment: you can access in angular js by calling from the id of the hiden field

Comment: @LDS: How would i set the value to the id? or better yet, would it be better if I did ng-init to the id of the hidden field and set that value in the scope.GetCurrentZip function?

Answer (score 0):

Below code of angular will give you the hiden value

```js
var hidenctl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#hidenid'));
var hidenvalue = hidenctl.val();
```